# CSS Classes in django-pagination package

Tags: python, css, templates, django-pagination

I'm tring to use  django-pagination package(http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pagination) and I found out that in pagination template they use the  following CSS classes:

```
<span class="current page">
<span class="disabled next">
etc
```

Why do they use classnames with space symbol? Is it normal? And how can I define classname with space symbol inside?

Comment: Surely a duplicate question. For example this explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051/when-did-browsers-start-supporting-multiple-classes-per-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class names do not have a space in them, it is the space that separates classnames; class names cannot have a space (though they can have a hypen, which is typically used in place of spaces in a class name).

The HTML `<span class="current page">` means that the styles for both the `current` and `page` classes apply. The same goes for the second excerpt in your question except the `disabled` and `next` classes apply.